# Why can't user using AM/PM see time created on 24 devices

Tags: ios, swift

1. In my application the user selects a date and the selected date is displayed in a bottom sheet on the other user's phone.
2. If both users' phones are in the 12 hour zone (AM-PM), there is no problem.
3. If the user using the phone in 12 time zone sends a clock to the user using the 24 time zone, the time appears to be successful.
4. However, if the user using 24 time zones sends a clock to the user using 12 time zones, the user cannot see the time. Because the function returns nil.
   (I used ÖÖ and ÖS control because of the distortions in Turkish time. AM/PM )

```
func utcTime(dateStr: String) -> String? {
    let isCurrentDevice12HoursFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)?.range(of: "a") != nil
    let isDateStr12HoursFormat = dateStr.last == "M"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let isPM = dateStr.contains("ÖS")
    let isAM = dateStr.contains("ÖÖ")
    dateFormatter.amSymbol = isAM ? "ÖÖ" : "AM"
    dateFormatter.pmSymbol = isPM ? "ÖS" : "PM"
    if dateStr.contains("ÖÖ") || dateStr.contains("ÖS") {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd a h:mm:ss"
    } else {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = isDateStr12HoursFormat ? "yyyy-MM-dd' 'h:mm:ss a" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    }
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = isCurrentDevice12HoursFormat ? "yyyy-MM-dd' 'h:mm:ss a" : "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Why are you using multiple formats? Use a single non-localized format.
Also, please read https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html especially the part about POSIX locale.

Comment: So, as the `DateFormatter` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) says, when showing dates in the UI, avoid changing all those `DateFormatter` properties, but rather just use `timeStyle` (and `dateStyle`) to display the dates in the UI, but when storing or transmitting dates, we use “Fixed Format Date Representations” as discussed in that document (e.g., use `ISO8601DateFormatter`). So, one formatter for the UI and another for fixed format scenarios.

Comment: Do you have a code sample for this?

Comment: The examples are in that link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

Answer (score 1):

This line solved my problem

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```